# Is there a way to prioritize bandwidth without QoS?

Tags: networking, router, bandwidth

i've got 2 pc's, and i use PC1 for gaming and 2nd PC is using my brother, so whenever he goes on the internet my ping in game raises and game becomes literaly unplayable. (happens with every game) So i would like to limit his connection but i don't have QoS option when i go to 192.168.1.1. I'm using huawei HG530. I also called my ISP and they told me that they don't know what is QoS. Fml. Note: everything goes thru LAN cable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could install software like [Netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) on your brothers computer and limit its bandwith usage there.

However he can probably uninstall it, if he thinks its slowing him down too much and you are not the sole administrator of his computer.

Comment: I have hundreds of questions, asking how to remove the malware known as Netlimiter, its extremely hard to remove.  I cannot suggest anyone use it, because many believe like I do, it to be basically worst then malware.

Comment: sorry did not know this, as i have not used netlimiter myself. is there any alternative to the promised features ?